# A problem with existance of the limit having $\limsup$ inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I had some problems with the existance of one limit so I avoided it and after some computations I obtained the folowing result:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|u_{n}-u\|^{2}_{X}\le0,$$
where $X$ is a Hilbert space. Now, does it imply that $\lim\|u_{n}-u\|=0$? I may introduce a new sequance let's say $(a_{n})$ such that $a_{n}=\|u_{n}-u\|^{2}_{X}$. So I have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\le0,$$
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\le0.$$
Still, it doesn't say much to me as far as the limit existance is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} \|u_n - u\|^2 \le 0$ does imply $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \|u_n - u\| = 0$. For since $\|u_n - u\| \ge 0$, then $\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} \|u_n - u\| \ge 0 \ge \limsup_{n\to \infty} \|u_n - u\|$, and so $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \|u_n - u\| = \limsup_{n\to \infty} \|u_n - u\| = 0$$